# nesC error to divide two integer when the partial result is minor of 1

Tags: c, printf, tinyos, nesc

This is a part of my code to explain my problem:

```
int64_t packet_tx=3;
int64_t packet_rx=5;
int64_t packet_loss;

printf("Packet_loss: %d",((packet_tx-packet_rx)/packet_tx)*100);
```

In this code is ever **packet_tx>=packet_rx**;

The result is an integer but the intermediate result is not an integer.
How can i resolve my problem? I tried to do cast with  double of the var packet_tx and packet_rx before the division.
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides casting to double, you also need to use the format specifier for double, `%lf`, in `printf()`.

```
printf("Packet_loss: %lf", ((double)(packet_tx-packet_rx)/(double)packet_tx)*100.0);
```